# get radio button value of a styled form using jquery

Tags: jquery, radio-button

i'm using a styled form that works on hiding the read radio button and replaces it with a label and an image. Now I want to get the checked value of the radio after clicking a button
here's the example
http://jsfiddle.net/c2veopa3/1/

css code

```
.example{
margin-bottom : 1.5em;
}

input[type=radio   ]:not(old){
width   : 28px;
margin  : 0;
padding : 0;
opacity : 0;
}

input[type=radio   ]:not(old) + label{
display      : inline-block;
margin-left  : -28px;
padding-left : 28px;
background   : url('http://mawk3y.net/cards/checks.png') no-repeat 0 0;
line-height  : 24px;
}

input[type=radio]:not(old):checked + label{
background-position : 0 -48px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply like this : http://jsfiddle.net/c2veopa3/2/

```
$("input[type=radio]:checked").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

what toggles old? Im guessing that's a class...

I'd change your css to match the following type of format. Also you should remove white space from attribute selector in second to last rule

```
input[type=radio]:not(.old):checked + label{ .. }
```

jquery

```
$('[type=radio]:checked:not(.old)') // should select it, input not necessary
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the relevance of the style is but this is straight from using your fiddle:

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    console.log($('input[type=radio]:checked').val());
});
```